# Select newest datetime column with related price column from same row

Tags: mysql, select, group-by

I have a table in my database which is tracking some prices. The columns are: `id`, `product`, `factory`, `seller`, `platform`, `price` and `inserted` (datetime).

Each 6 hour on every day there are new records stored with the current price.
Example:

```
1, Product 1, Factory 1, Seller 1, Platform 1, 99.99, 2019-08-07 02:12:35
2, Product 1, Factory 1, Seller 1, Platform 1, 95.99, 2019-08-06 20:12:35
```

Now I try to select the latest entries with prices. One entry should be unique by `product`, `factory`, `seller`, `platform`. So my sql query is now:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM prices 
 GROUP 
    BY product
     , factory
     , seller
     , platform
 ORDER 
    BY inserted DESC
     , price ASC
```

But how can I now fetch the newest prices for each entry? One solution is to select `` MAX(`inserted`) `` but how to get the price from the `` MAX(`inserted`) `` row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select p1.* from 
prices p1
join
(
  SELECT `product`, `factory`, `seller`, `platform`, max(inserted) as max_inserted
  FROM `prices` 
  GROUP BY `product`, `factory`, `seller`, `platform` 
) p2 on p1.product = p2.product
    and p1.factory = p2.factory
    and p1.seller = p2.seller
    and p1.platform = p2.platform
    and p1.inserted = p2.max_inserted
```

The inner select gets the latest date for each group. Then join against that to get only the relevant records that contain the prices.